# Enviar datos de preferencia a MercadoPago con Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mercadopago

Estoy haciendo una página en  Python 3.4 y Django 1.7, usando el checkout básico de MercadoPago, pero quiero enviar mas info del comprador que lo que propone el básico pero me sale el error que no es json serializable. Necesito enviar los sig datos:

```
    preference = {
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "Título del art.",
            "quantity": 1,
            "currency_id": "ARS",  # Available currencies at: https://api.mercadopago.com/currencies
            "unit_price": 1800
        }
    ],
    "payers": [
        {
            "name": nombre,
            "surname": apellido,
            "email": email,
            "phone.number": telefono,
            "identification":
                {
                    "type": tipo_documento,
                    "number": num_doc,
                }, # identification
            "address":
                {
                    "zip_code": cp,
                    "street_name": calle,
                    "street_number": num_calle,
                }  # address
        },
        ],
    "back_urls": [
        {
            "success": redirect('venta_exitosa_r'),
            "failure": redirect('venta_fallida_r'),
            "pending": redirect('venta_pendiente_r')
        },
    ]

}

mp = mercadopago.MP(settings.CLIENT_ID, settings.CLIENT_SECRET)
preferenceresult = mp.create_preference(preference)
url = preferenceresult["response"]["init_point"]
return url
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Encuentro rapidamente algunos errores, la seccion payers deberia llamarse payer en singular ademas de que back_urls deberia ser un objeto ya que success, failure y pending serian sus propiedades, no son una lista de un arreglo, quizas con eso podrias probar, sumaria si puedes explicar un poco mas el error que recibes.

Comment: @JoelIbaceta este es el error "<django.http.response.HttpResponseRedirect object at 0x0487BF10> is not JSON serializable" y es como vos decis "payer" Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como has comentado, y como el error te dice:

> "django.http.response.HttpResponseRedirect object at 0x0487BF10 is not JSON serializable

Quiere decir que el modulo de que está serializando, no serializa objetos, debes saber que la función `redirect()` retorna un objeto, los objetos usualmente no se serializan, así que es mejor pasar datos sólidos, es decir si el contenido del JSON (o diccionario) que tienes, fuera destinado a javascrpit, entonces javascript no sabría que hacer con un objeto de python, que ademas, le llega como un string.

La Solución rápida que veo a tu problema, es en vez de usar redirect, ya que esta funcion sirve para hacer una redirección al momento que es llamada, y supongo que quieres pasar es una url. usa `reverse`, asi:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

...
"back_urls": [
    {
        "success": reverse('venta_exitosa_r'),
        "failure": reverse('venta_fallida_r'),
        "pending": reverse('venta_pendiente_r')
    },
...
```

Lo que hará es reemplazar tus redirects por la url que deseas a string... y así ya puedes serializar.

Cualquier pregunta, comenta.

Comment: Perfecto!! Solucionado. Mil gracias!!